# How can including a header cause a linker error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I have two fairly unrelated cpp files, let's call them `simplify.cpp` and `migrate.cpp`, and a header file `server.h` from another library.

When I try to include `server.h` into `simplify.cpp`, I get a linker error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol in both cpp files.

I have checked that the symbol it's referring to is indeed defined in the library, and it's even used elsewhere. It is something to the effect of:

```
SomeObject::SetValue( const std::shared_ptr<Value>& value )
```

which overrides a base class implementation that does nothing.

I'm not even sure if any of this is even relavant but some more info: The base class implementation is defined in its header (just empty braces), while that of `SomeObject` is defined in its cpp file. The inheritance is fairly deep and involves some templates but that has never been an issue.

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be? And why does it cause a link error in another file that I'm not even touching?

I'm using VS2012.

Comment: The answer to your question title is simple: Including a header can introduce new symbols. If the linker can not find these symbols (for example, because you forgot to link against the library), you will get a linker error.
The more interesting question is why you get that error in both files, which I don't know. Maybe the linker lost track of the origin of the symbol for some reason?

Comment: Just because you use the #include directive to some header file doesn't mean that it is going to work as you would expect. This will work when you are using #include where the *.h files are files that you created for your own project within your solution's directory. When you begin to include external headers or 3d party libraries, not only do you need to use the #include directive, but you also have to tell visual studio where the *.h file is located along with any dependencies such as any *.lib or *.dll files that pertains to that library.

Comment: (...continued) If you don't Visual Studio can not resolve any symbols, classes or functions that are defined in the *.h file. Your *.h files are simply declarations where your .cpp files are the definitions - implementations. You need to go into your projects' settings - properties and set the linker to link against any needed libraries and to point where those directories are located.

Comment: I guess you should show the actual code and error messages, otherwise this question probably won't lead anywhere.

Comment: Several potentially guiding questions:  Is the library a DLL or a static one? (if it is a DLL the functions/classes consumed outside must be dllexported) What is the 'other place' SomeObject::SetValue is called? is it in the same library as simplify.cpp?

You can also try posting here a /VERBOSE linker output and we'll try to help analyze it.   I'm aware of at least one VC++ 'design bug' that caused similar behaviour for me in the past (http://ofekshilon.com/2014/06/13/vector-deleting-destructor-and-weak-linkage/).

Comment: It's a static library. The other places actually use a similar related function and so it turns out the only other place it's called is in that `migrate.cpp`.

The entire solution is actually pretty colossal and so I've concluded that somewhere along the way, we screwed up some dependencies or other. The verbose linker output is... very long. I don't really think it's worth anyone's time sifting through it, but I appreciate the offer :)

I've just changed the code to use the related function instead. It's deeply unsatisfying but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is a linker error is because your header file has said that

"the function `SomeObject::SetValue( const std::shared_ptr<Value>& value )` exists, somewhere"

but the linker cannot find the definition of this function. If it is indeed defined in the same library that you are working with, check the syntax of everything in your definition. Perhaps this is due to a typo.

Comment: The only problem I have with this as the answer: I've included headers that forward declare unused functions and I don't get linker errors, though I'm using gcc/clang/sunstudio, not visual studio.

Comment: Indeed, unless you _odr-use_ such functions, they do not need to be defined. This answer is essentially wrong.

Comment: It seemed implicit to me from his question that this function was not unused. I think it a bit of a stretch to say that this answer is "wrong" because I did not make this clear. But, yes, it should be been made explicit in my response I suppose.